# C++ - Replacing "_" with a character

Tags: c++, arrays, replace

Using C++, I'm trying to make a hangman game to become better at using C++ and programming in general. Anyways, the issue I'm facing is that I'm not sure how to replace the dashes within a string with the letter the user has guessed.

I think my problem is with the fact the word chosen is randomly chosen from an array and I'm not sure how to go about finding the positions within the randomly chosen string which consists of the guessed character.

I have commented out the area that's causing the issue.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <array>
#include <string>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <cstddef>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string words[3] = {"stack", "visual", "windows"};
    string guess;

    cout << "Welcome to hangman.\n";
    cout << "\n";

    srand(time(NULL));

    int RandIndex = rand() % 3;
    string selected = words[RandIndex];

    for (int i = 1; i <= selected.size(); i++) {
        cout << "_ ";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\nType in a letter: ";
    cin >> guess;
    cout << "\n";

    if (selected.find(guess) != string::npos) {
        /*for (int i = 1; i <= selected.size(); i++) {
            if (selected.find(guess) != string::npos) {
                cout << "_ ";
            } else {
                cout << guess << " ";
            }
        }*/
    } else {
        cout << "\nNay!\n";
        cout << "\n";
    }

    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\n";

    system("PAUSE");
    return 0;
}
```

I was thinking about using the `replace()` function but the problem I face here is that I'm not replacing the string within `selected` variable but sort of iterating through the word itself, if that made any sense whatsoever?

Comment: I had to do a hangman game when I was at uni. I stored the word in a string and had a vector of distinct characters in the string. When displaying each character in the word you check if its in the vector, and if it is, then display an underscore instead. When the user guesses correctly you remove the character from the vector.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You actually need to use a second string to store the "guessed" string; this is because you need to keep track of all the guessed letters and display them.

something like :

```
    string s ="test";
    string t="";  //empty string

    for(int i=0;i<s.size();i++)
        t.append("_");    //initialize the guess string
    cout<<t<<'\n'; 

    char c;
    cin >> c;

    int pos = s.find(c);   //get the first occurrence of the entered char
    while(pos!=-1)         //look for all occurrences and replaced them in the guess string
    {
      t.replace(pos,1,1,c);   
      pos = s.find(c, pos+1);

    }
```

Comment: On Visual Studio, my equivalent of the line `t.replace(pos,1,1,c);` gives me the error 


`'std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc> &std::basic_string<_Elem,_Traits,_Alloc>::replace(unsigned int,unsigned int,const _Elem *,unsigned int)' : cannot convert parameter 3 from 'int' to 'const char *'`; why is that?

Comment: that usually happens if you pass a string instead of a char; so make sure c does not include the string termination '\0'; or you could try passing c[0], which should be the first chracter in the string.

Comment: mint that in your code you are reading into a string variable not a char variable. That's probably why you get the error - I edited my response for clarifications

Comment: Ah, I had c as a string data type. This solution worked, thank you very much.

Answer (score 2):

Use a second string, that is initialized with the underscores. If the `find` function *doesn't* return `string::npos` it returns the position in the string, and this is the same position you should change in the string with the underscores as well.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to maintain some extra state while looping - to keep track of which letters have / haven't been guessed.

You could add a new string current_state which is initially set to the same length as the word but all underscores.  Then, when the player guesses a letter, you find all instances of that letter in the original word, and replace the underscore with the letter guessed, at all the positions found but in current_state.

Answer (score 0):

First i would initialize a new string to show the hidden word:

```
string  stringToDisplay = string(  selected.length(), '_');
```

Then For each letter given by the user i would loop like this:
(assuming guess is letter)

```
size_t searchInitPos = 0;
size_t found = selected.find(guess, searchInitPos));
if (found == string::npos)  
{
    cout << "\nNay!\n";
            cout << "\n";
}
while( found != string::npos)
{
    stringToDisplay[found] = guess;
    searchInitPos = found+1;
    found = selected.find(guess, searchInitPos));
}
cout << stringToDisplay;
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score -1):

I think it should be that:

```
string words[3] = {"stack", "visual", "windows"};
char guess;
string display;

cout << "Welcome to hangman.\n";
cout << "\n";

srand(time(NULL));

int RandIndex = rand() % 3;
string selected = words[RandIndex];

for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
    display.insert(0, "_ ");
}
cout << display;

while(display.find("_ ") != string::npos) {
    cout << "\n";
    cout << "\nType in a letter: ";
    cin >> guess;
    cout << "\n";

    bool flag = false;
    for (int i = 0; i < selected.size(); i++) {
        if (selected[i] == guess) {
            display.replace(i*2, 1, 1, guess);
            flag = true;
        }
    }
    if (!flag) {
        cout << "\nNay!\n";
        cout << "\n";
    } else {
        cout << display;
    }

}
```

Comment: actually no it would not; this will only work for the first character. But you need to keep track of and display all the guessed characters